# ¿Cómo puedo importar desde excel una base de datos que contenga fechas?

Tags: r

Tengo esta base de datos en excel que es así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando la importo a R

```
> arroz <- read_table(choose.files(), col_names = T, col_types = cols( +   fecha = col_date("%d/%m/%y"), +   precio = col_number() + )) 
Warning message: The following named parsers don't match the column names: fecha, precio
```

la primera columna no me sale como fechas sino como carácter, y lo que se requiere es que esa base de datos sea serie de tiempo

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código que estás usando para importar el archivo excel?

Comment: Este es el codigo > arroz <- read_table(choose.files(), col_names = T, col_types = cols(
+   fecha = col_date("%d/%m/%y"),
+   precio = col_number()
+ ))
Warning message:
The following named parsers don't match the column names: fecha, precio

Comment: Y que tipo de archivo estás importando? lo pregunto por que `read_table` no lee archivos xls o xlsx sino archivos con datos separados por espacio. Si es así, podrías compartir al menos las primeras filas del archivo?

Comment: un archivo csv en la la descripción de la pregunta están las primeras filas del archivo csv

Comment: Si, la ví, pero parece un printscreen directo del excel, con lo cual no se puede apreciar el real formato de los datos en el archivo csv.

Comment: los encabezados estan forma general, ene-96.... fecha personalizada, los numeros en general

Comment: No hay `parser` que te procese ese formato de fecha, vas a tener que importar la columna como un caracter y luego hacer una transformación para convertir la misma en fecha.

Comment: Lo que me dices confirma entonces que el csv tiene otro formato que el que muestra tu pregunta, de ahí mi pedido a que copies las primeras filas del archivo csv. De todas formas, te sugiero que veas la respuesta que te dejé en tu otra pregunta, ya que imagino que debería resolver ambas cuestiones.

Comment: fecha precio 
01-01-96 239913
01-02-96 261309
01-03-96 278129
01-04-96 286218
este el que convertir la primera linea es general 
01-01-1996 esta en tipo fecha
el precio es en general

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98250/discussion-between-patricio-moracho-and-davitz).

Comment: En la muestra que has pegado, el separador no es el espacio sino el tab \t, con read_table() no va a funcionar, prueba con read_table2(). Al menos con esta muestra, pude importar los datos sin problemas